# Redefining `require` on the client (but not on server) for code-sharing

Tags: node.js, include, express, coffeescript

I want to share a piece of coffeescript code between the server and the client on Express.
I linked the file from the server directory into the `/public` directory, so it can be loaded by the client.
It does have external dependencies, which I resolve statically for the client. To remove the error messages when the client tries to call `require`, I thought a simple conditional declaration would do.

```
console.log require
unless require?
  require = (what) ->
    console.info "this is the client, you asked me to load #{what}"
    return {}
```

However, when run on the server, `undefined` will be printed and `require` will be overridden. The same happens for embedded Javascript:

```
`if( typeof require == "undefined" )
  var require = function(what) {
    console.info( "this is the client, you asked me to load "+what );
    return {};
  }
`
```

If I only run:

```
console.log require
```

on the server, it prints an object structure, as expected.
It seems that `require` is injected after at least the conditional has been evaluated and executed.

How can I override `require` safely, or what other paradigm might I use for sharing code between client and server?

Comment: When I put `console.log(typeof require);` at the top of a module, it prints `function`, so I'm not sure why you're experiencing something different. I don't know if it's possible that Coffeescript is in some way interfering (although that would seem odd). You might start simple, or even with pure JS, and work your way up from there. If you can get it to work in pure JS, then try comparing that to the CS output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [browserify](http://browserify.org/) for sharing code between the client and server.  It allows you to write your javascript as you would for the server following the common js pattern, but provides a mechanism to build your module for client-side where **require()** works in the browser.

CoffeeScript is supported with browserify via a **transform** process.  [Coffeeify](https://github.com/substack/coffeeify) is one implementation of a transform implementation for CoffeeScript.

Comment: https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/85bbf6097b0237b921ef2bb232c2dc807604e865/687474703a2f2f737562737461636b2e6e65742f696d616765732f62726f777365726966792f62726f777365726966792e706e67